# Oracle xdb-xmlparser source code

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxp

Related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929790/saxparseexception-xml-20221-invalid-char-in-text), does anyone know if I can get the source code for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>xdb-xmlparser</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where have you got the artifact? It is not in a public repository as I see.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't get the source code from companies like Oracle. If you are investigating a bug or an strange behavior, decompile it and you'll get almost the original source code without comments.

Use any tool like jad or GUI tool DJ Java Decompilerr.

It's a good practice in order to investigate issues, but not supported by Oracle:)

Answer (score 2):

(Not so) long time ago, my company has been trying to get the source of Oracle ADF Framework. It went the following way:

1. We posted a question at Metalink (now it's called [My Oracle Support](https://support.oracle.com), you need to be Oracle Partner, or have a support subscription bought from them to post there).
2. They sent us an about 6-pages long form, with the rules saying how to store the source code, who can access it and what type of crazy hat do we have to wear when reading it. Well, this sort of stuff.
3. They required this form to be signed by some high executive, with my name on it, as the person having access to the code, and fax it back to them manually signed.
4. Few days later, they posted a link to a ZIP file with sources on the Metalink (in the answer to our question, so nobody else could get access to it).

We did this twice - for ADF 10g and ADF 11g. Both times the same way.

So basically - your best bet is to contact Oracle.

Here is a [reference to Oracle's documentation stating that the above is possible for ADF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b25947/web_testdebug005.htm), quote:

> You can obtain complete source code for Oracle ADF by opening a service request with Oracle Worldwide Support and requesting it.

P.S. There are also other ways, like decompiling Oracle JARs, but be aware, that his may violate the license.